# Google Play App Layout Example

Tags: android

I would like to copy the Google Play App layout for my own application. Can anyone point me to documentation or examples that show how to implement:

1. the horizontal scrolling with two panels (title bar and body)
2. how they make the tile (grid) layout in the main page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for ViewPager for the sectioned screen swipe with title bar you described.

For the grid panel, I did not look into app code but I predict they would just have predefined several xml layout they can use. Then when they update the content they just switch it to pass one of the flag to config the layout they wanted to use for display. Or they could just pass JSON string with RelativeLayout's parameter to style the page. I am just speculating here. Maybe someone else could shine the lights on it.